# Cross Compiling SDL C++ application to Android

Tags: android, c++, c, compilation, cross-compiling

I want to compile an open source C++ project to Android . The project runs on Linux but needs to be compiled to 32 bit.

Here is the output of the compile process
https://pastebin.com/9CkVVD9i

Here is my CMAKE file with which I am working with.
https://pastebin.com/eMDntghP

Problem is that when I compile I see tons of these errors.

```
  /home/qndel/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/lib64/clang/7.0.2/include/mmintrin.h:324:19: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_punpcklwd'
      return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_punpcklwd((__v4hi)__m1, (__v4hi)__m2);
                    ^
  /home/qndel/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/lib64/clang/7.0.2/include/mmintrin.h:345:19: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_punpckldq'
      return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_punpckldq((__v2si)__m1, (__v2si)__m2);
                    ^
  fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
  20 errors generated.
  ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

I am not sure what to think apart from maybe I am targeting the wrong architecture and googling seems to return not very good results.

Let me know if you need a link to the project .

Comment: `__builtin_ia32_punpcklwd` is an _intel_ `x86` intrinsic call for `x86` SIMD instructions. Android [in most cases] uses the `arm` architecture which has no such equivalent.

Comment: I was thinking this, how can I use the correct toolchain?

Comment: I just looked it up, and SDL seems to come with Gradle build scripts for targeting android. `docs/README-android.md` seems to have some detailed instructions. Did you try those?

Comment: I don't think the problem is with SDL . I compiled a helloworld sdl app for tests and it worked.  When I tried the opensource app and made my own CMAKE file I ran into weirdness .

Comment: Ok @HolyBlackCat I have to recant. I think you might be on to something SDL is importing the lib which is using this as a header. I will look at them. I think this is weird that it didn't cause problems with hello world programs but now it is throwing a fit.Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, I switched compilers to g++ 4.4.9 removed the #include  from the repo.

To download the compiler:
https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/older_releases

**In your local.properties add line**

```
ndk.dir=/path/to/your/ndk-bundle
```

And the thing worked that helped the most was installing the in your app build.gradle

You can specify the GCC compiler (which is no longer supported but my project requires it)

```
externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                arguments '-DBUILD_TESTING=OFF', '-DANDROID_TOOLCHAIN=gcc'
                cppFlags "-w -std=c++14"
            }
```

I hope this helps someone . I only had to make minor changes to compile the app.